# Android Studio – Running and Debugging Builds over Wi-Fi on Mac OS

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, adb, android-wifi

How to Run and Debug builds wirelessly (over Wi-Fi) in Android Studio 3.2 for macOS?

Is it possible to setup it via Android Studio's UI, not via Android Debug Bridge (`adb`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android Studio uses `adb`. You can not avoid `adb` usage to connect to Android devices.
If you can connect at least the first time device to pc:

1. Connect device via USB and make sure debugging is working, then run:

   ```
   adb tcpip 5555
   adb connect :5555
   ```

   Disconnect USB and proceed with wireless debugging.
2. When you're done and want to switch back to USB debugging, run:

   adb -s :5555
3. To find the IP address of your device, go to Settings > Wi-Fi > Advanced > IP Address on your device or run `adb` shell `netcfg`.

No root required. Only one device can be debugged at a time.

There was a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp). In this link, you will find the base article for this post.

Comment: Thank. Is it suitable for Mac OS?

Comment: Why not? The mechanism is the same.